# Node db connection won't getting data from server

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am using node app, i created a mongodb named as "staff" in my db. while i use and see my terminal that show the data availabilty ( 1 data i inserted ), but when i return the same using node function, i am always getting empty array('[]')..

here is my node functions:

```
var 
    appRoot = __dirname,
    express = require("express"),
    path = require("path"),
    mongoose = require("mongoose"),
    app = express();

    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/myOffice'); //i am connecting to myOffice db

    var colligue = mongoose.model('staff', new mongoose.Schema({
        name : String
    }));


    app.configure(function(){
      app.use(express.json());
      app.use(express.urlencoded());
      app.use(app.router);
      app.use(express.static(path.join(appRoot, "public")));

    });




app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.send("I am hearing!");
});

app.get('/staff', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/static.html');
});

app.get('/api/staffs', function(req, res) {
    return colligue.find(function(err, staffs) {
        if (!err) {
            return res.send(staffs); // finding from colligue but always getting empty array '[]'
        }
    })
});

app.listen(3000);
```

in the terminal i can view my data:

```
  db.staff.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("52c16190b5832172661967ba"), "name" : "servent1" }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Mongoose pluralizes (and lower-cases) your model name to determine the collection name it's tied to.  So in this case it would use `staffs` instead of `staff`.

To fix this, you can explicitly set the collection name using the third parameter to `mongoose.model`:

```
var colligue = mongoose.model('staff', new mongoose.Schema({
    name : String
}), 'staff');
```